# Best way to Hide or Show contents of div based on list based menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dojo

I have to show or hide contents of div based on the menu selection.

Below is my structure

```
    <div id = "menuContainer">
        <p>Menu</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Menu Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub Menu One</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub Menu Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub Menu Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub Menu Four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Menu Three</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="row"> 
    <div id="home" > <h1>This is Home Page </h1></div>
      <div id="MenuTwo" class="content"> <h1>This is  Menu Two page</h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuOne" class="content"><h1> This is Sub Menu One Page</h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuTwo" class="content"><h1>This is Sub Menu Two Page </h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuThree" class="content"> <h1>This is Sub Menu THree Page</h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuFour" class="content"><h1> This is Sub Menu Four Page</h1></div>
      <div id="MenuThree" class="content"> <h1>This is  Menu THree Page</h1></div>
      <div id="MenuFour" class="content"> <h1>This is  Menu Four Page</h1></div>
      <div id="Contact" class="content"> <h1>This is Contact  Page</h1></div>
</div>
```

I found also an example on [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906685/dojo-show-or-hide-divs-based-on-selection-in-a-list) which does a similar thing.

It seems to use `Dojo` which I am not familiar with. Is there any other way of doing it with an easy script?

My fiddle example:http://jsfiddle.net/bG46Z/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSFIDDLE [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/bG46Z/5/)

**The JQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.row div').hide();
    $('#home').show(); // if you want to show the home div first
    $('#menuContainer a').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.row div').hide();
        $(id).fadeIn("250");
    });
});
```

**The new HTML :**

```
 <div id = "menuContainer">
        <p>Menu</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#MenuTwo">Menu Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#SubMenuOne">Sub Menu One</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#SubMenuTwo">Sub Menu Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#SubMenuThree">Sub Menu Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#SubMenuFour">Sub Menu Four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#MenuThree">Menu Three</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="row"> 
    <div id="home" > <h1>This is Home Page </h1></div>
      <div id="MenuTwo" class="content"> <h1>This is  Menu Two page</h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuOne" class="content"><h1> This is Sub Menu One Page</h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuTwo" class="content"><h1>This is Sub Menu Two Page </h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuThree" class="content"> <h1>This is Sub Menu THree Page</h1></div>
      <div id="SubMenuFour" class="content"><h1> This is Sub Menu Four Page</h1></div>
      <div id="MenuThree" class="content"> <h1>This is  Menu THree Page</h1></div>
      <div id="MenuFour" class="content"> <h1>This is  Menu Four Page</h1></div>
      <div id="Contact" class="content"> <h1>This is Contact  Page</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will accept your answer, as i am but familiar with jQuery rather than Dojo. Thanks to other who also replied.

Comment: is their a possibility that we can just show the element rather than scroll down, At present code works like a book mark and if page section has lot of text then it scroll down the page. I just want to show the content without without scroling down. I tried to use `$( "body" ).scrollTop( 0 );` but it doesn't work.  example http://jsfiddle.net/bG46Z/7/

Comment: do you mean that whene the client click on the link the page dont scroll ?

Comment: In a way yes for desktop version i don't want it to scroll, but for mobile version your code is fine. can you change this code so that it doent scroll down in case screen size is great than 900px;

Comment: I tried few option but it still scroll up if either you click `home or Menu two link`

Comment: I applied same to this example but it is not working http://jsfiddle.net/bG46Z/13/. In your example it is working for some reason but this example has broken HTML which i had added by mistake.

Comment: It works some time but sometimes it doesnt http://jsfiddle.net/bG46Z/14/ I have updated example & when i switch in between pages like Home, Menu two & Contact it breaks sometime i am not sure is it just my FF browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58003/discussion-between-youness-and-knowledgeseeker).

Comment: Quite wired, It works fine in IE & Chrome just gives me unexpected result in FF. Anyways thanks for your help appreciate that.

Comment: no problem man if i find a solution i'll post here :) good luck man

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the same thing in Dojo, it's also possible:

```js
require([ "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/NodeList-traverse" ], function(query, domAttr) {
    query("#menuContainer a").on("click", function(evt) {
        query(".row > div")
            .style("display", "none")
            .parents(".row")
            .query(domAttr.get(evt.target, "href"))
            .style("display", "block");
    });
});
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/YBae9/